# Sending order confirmation email in magento 2 programmatically

Tags: magento2, email, order-email, programmatically, order-confirmation-email

Normally I would do something like

```
<?php

use \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender;
use \Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class MyClass
{
    private $orderSender;
    private $order;

    public function __construct(
        OrderSender $orderSender,
        Order $order
    ) {
        $this->orderSender = $orderSender;
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    public function sendEmail($import, $orderItems)
    {
        $this->order->load($orderId);
        $this->orderSender->send($order, true);
    }
}
```

I have noted $this->order->load() has been deprecated but $this->orderSender->send() expects \Magento\Sales\Model\Order

Therefore my question is how would I send order confirmation emails without using deprecated methods.

Also as a note "Asynchronous sending" for is disabled Sales Emails

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try repository for loading order. So your modified class looks like:

```
<?php

use \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

class MyClass
{
    private $orderSender;
    private $order;

    public function __construct(
        OrderSender $orderSender,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
    ) {
        $this->orderSender = $orderSender;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }

    public function sendEmail($import, $orderItems)
    {
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
        $this->orderSender->send($order, true);
    }
}
```